# Can a helicopter fly with just one blade?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, aircraft

I read somewhere that the main helicopter body will also spin in the opposite direction to maintain angular momentum. Is this true?

Comment: There are plenty of 1 bladed helicopters, look at the Robinson models,  but you mean half a blade? Or do you mean it needs a tail rotor to stop spinning.

Comment: Related: [Possible to fly with counterbalanced single blade engines?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21354/)

Comment: Do you mean a single [blade](http://www.smartrotorsystems.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Balde3.png) or a single [rotor](http://s3images.coroflot.com/user_files/individual_files/original_585147_gtumngl_ix6cawtw6rhxenwbk.jpg)? A rotor consists of several (generally three or four) blades, and normal helicotpers have two different rotors. Would you count [a Robinson helicopter](http://www.lahelicopters.com/images/sales/r66/r66_2.jpg) as a single-blade helicopter?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I am pretty sure, by one blade, the OP means just the main rotor assembly, irrespective of blade number. It's "what if" failure  of the back end that I _think_ is the question.

Comment: @count_to_10 Yeah, but the language still needs to be fixed. If the OP really means "with just the main rotor assembly", the post should say that. As it is, a literal reading of the question implies half of the Robinson blade - which is a valid question too, but it would need to be mentioned more explicitly. Either way, Chris John needs to clarify what he means.

Comment: @count_to_10 I'm happy to hear it. It's just part of being a good Web citizen.

Comment: I think your title and your question body are actually two different questions. I think the answers: 1) theoretically yes, but practically it would probably step over its engineering limits 2) yes.

Comment: I wrote one 'blade', don't know why everyone is getting confused with 'rotor'( they don't even have one common letter haha). In all seriousness, I know nothing about helicopter machinery, this was just a question on classical mechanics(physics).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, without a means of counteracting the torque caused by the main rotor, the helicopter will rotate pretty much uncontrollably.

There is plenty of footage on YouTube,  if you have the stomach to watch it, of what happens when the tail rotor fails.

[How Helicopters Fly](http://www.decodedscience.org/how-do-helicopters-fly/20418) gives you more details.

[image]

<sup>[Image source: Driemond fire department.](http://www.opendagbrandweerdriemond.nl/materieel/detail/trauma-helikopter)</sup>

If the tail rotor failed on the above helicopter, it would spin in the opposite direction as a consequence  of the law of conservation of angular  momentum.

One method of recovery is to immediately shut off the engine, and allow the helicopter to autorotate which, although disorienting to the pilot, will reduce the spinning of the helicopter body.

From [Autorotation](http://www.copters.com/pilot/trfail_cruise.html)

> If the tail rotor fails in flight, engine torque can no longer be countered by the tail rotor, and uncontrolled spinning of the aircraft is a possibility. Most manufacturers call for an immediate autorotation.
>
> An autorotation is a natural way to deal with an inflight tail rotor failure since it reduces torque to zero. One problem with an autorotation is that it will be difficult or impossible for the pilot to align the landing gear with ground track during touchdown.

Comment: An example of a 1-bladed helicopter doing autorotation is all around us: [*maple seeds*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4urT74yq6c).

Comment: @MikeDunlavey now I know the difference between sycamore seeds and maple seeds, I saw a group of  one or other of them falling today.